# Can I do this in only one query?

Tags: sql, mysql

Merry christmas everyone,

I Know my way around SQL but I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.

First here are my tables (examples)

**User**

```
id
name
```

**friend**

```
 from //userid
 to //userid
```

If user 1 is friend with user 10
then you a row with 1,10.
User 1 cannot be friend with user 10 if user 10 is not friend with user 1
so you have 
1,10
10,1

It may look weird but I need those two rows per relations.

Now I'm trying to make a query to select the users that have the most mutual friend with a given user.

For example User 1 is friend with user 10,9 and 7 and user 8 is friend with 10,9 and 7 too ,I want to suggest user 1 to invite him (like facebook).

I want to get like the 10 first people with the most mutual friend.

The output would be like

User,NumOfMutualFriends

I dont know if that can be done in a single query ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think it should like User1, User2, Mutual Friends? If you have only 1 user, how can you know if that user has 10 mutual friends with whom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.id, COUNT(*) FROM
user as u1, user as u2, friend as f1, friend as f2
WHERE u1.id = f1.to AND u2.id = f1.from AND -- f1 and f2 are friends 
u2.id = f2.to AND f2.from = 1234 -- and f2 is my friend, so I have a mutual friend with f1
GROUP BY u1.id
```

EDIT1:
This is just a general idea.  Note that the count will be inaccurate, there will be duplicates.  You'd have to play with some real data to tweak the query to eliminate all the duplicates (or find a real DBA)

EDIT2: 
Also I suspect that this is probably not realistic as you are essentially doing a join of with at least n^4 results for the number of users.  Which will get pretty bad even if you have 100 of them.  So I'm pretty sure Facebook is doing something interesting.  No idea what.

Comment: Umm I wonder how we can do it better than... Too bad fb is not on GitHub :p

Comment: they probably try to detect cliques of users and search them.  Or maybe they make a list of your friends and then look at just their friends for people to suggest to you.

Answer (score 0):

> If user 1 is friend with user 10 then you a row with 1,10. User 1 cannot be friend with user 10 if user 10 is not friend with user 1 so you have 1,10 10,1
>
> It may look weird but I need those two rows per relations.

In this very case you don't, actually. :) That's called "**redundancy**". Note that if you keep only "non-duplicate" entries in this case, you can emulate what you have now with a simple query or a view. Hence, you don't need to duplicate the data in the table itself.

---

For your question, the answer would be something like:

```
SELECT User.id, COUNT(friend.to)
FROM User
LEFT JOIN friend ON User.id = friend.from
WHERE friend.to = 12345              --your target user id goes here
GROUP BY User.id
ORDER BY COUNT(friend.to) DESC
```

Comment: I think this just gives you the list of people who are friends with 12345?

Comment: Actually I need those row because I store more info such as date and time and the friend group and so on.. I'm testing out you answer now

Comment: @MK yes, I believe that's what Pate means by "a query to select the users that have the most mutual friend with a **given user** ".

Comment: @Pate OK, if there are more columns than just from and to, and the remaining columns differ in corresponding relations, then yes, that makes sense now :).

Comment: @Kos Actually MK is right I'm not looking for that, Your answers gives 7,9,10 but I want it to show 8 with 3 mutual friends. Acording to my example...

Comment: @Kos he wants to find people who he has mutual friends with, not just the list of friends.